# Angular4 Refresh page goes to home page

Tags: angular

Hi i defined route as under

```js
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: DashboardsAlpha, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardsAlpha},
  { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent},
  { path: 'order/createOrderStep2', component: CreateOrderComponent }
]}
```

When i click on client url it goes to client page. But when i click browser refresh button on any of child page it always goes to Dashboard page. Please suggest me what is wrong
I found one suggestion on stack overflow and that is

```html
<base href="/">
    <!-- Set the base href -->
    <script>document.write('<base href="'+ document.location +'"/>'</script>
```

But this did not work

Comment: All the examples show this syntax as `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}`, but I'm not sure why `component` would not work.